# Docker run Exited 1 httpd

Tags: linux, apache, shell, http, docker

i have create a configuration on an Image of an http server of apache,
i have install the last image and do some stuff in the dockerfile:

```
# Updated as of Aug 16, 2017
# FROM specified which image i want to download
# Needs to be provided before any other section of code.
FROM httpd:latest

#Author of the Docker File
MAINTAINER Pictolearn

# Copy the following directory
COPY pictolearn-sample/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/pictolearn

 # Copy httpd.conf with changes to the root directory
 COPY httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf
```

afther that i have do:

```
docker build -t my-httpd .
docker run -itd --name my-http-container-1 -p 5555:80 my-httpd:latest
```

but if i take the status i have exit = 1

```
 docker ps -a
 CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND              CREATED           
 STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
 40dc04bcfb2a        my-httpd:latest     "httpd-foreground"   5 
 minutes ago       Exited (1) 5 minutes ago                       my- 
 http-container-1
```

i don't know why it dosn't work
that's the logs result:

```
AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit httpd.conf and replase to

```
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

**update**

You can add at the end of the file, but add to around LoadModule's is better.

After that remove container and images and rebuild again

Comment: after that i had to rebuild image?
P.S. i can put that string at the end of the file or is indifferent?