# Docker httpd:alpine image exits with code 1

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run some basic html pages using `httpd` docker image.

Dockerfile

```
FROM httpd:alpine

COPY ./views /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/    # where my html pages stored

COPY httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

RUN httpd -v

EXPOSE 7074
```

httpd.conf

```
ServerName localhost
Listen 7074
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'

frontend_image:
    image: frontend_image
    build: 
      context: ./frontend_image
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    network_mode: "host"
    env_file: "./api.env"
    depends_on: 
      - apigateway
```

Then : `sudo docker-compose up --build`

`RUN httpd -v` gives:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.43 (Unix)
Server built:   Apr 24 2020 15:46:58
```

But

> Project_frontend_image_1 exited with code 1

How can I add an Entry-point to `httpd`, as I do not have `apachectl2` in `/usr/sbin`.

refered : [Docker run Exited 1 httpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49131463/docker-run-exited-1-httpd)

Edit :

I have tried `docker run -dit --name my-apache-app -p 7575:80 -v "$PWD":/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4`
and it works.

Comment: Are there any further log messages?  Why do you need it to run with `network_mode: host`?  (This will prevent it from connecting to the `apigateway` container, for example, which may be related to your problem.)

Comment: @DavidMaze No logs, I have tried it.
I have removed `network_mode: host`, yet problem there.
I used this as its easy to connect all services from localhost with ports.

Comment: Try to run the docker image in interactive mode (-it) which will provide any errors if there are

Comment: @janitha000 I have added `stdin_open: true` and `tty: true` to my docker-compose file, yet same result. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249744/interactive-shell-using-docker-compose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this is a problem with `httpd.conf` file rather than the Docker image.

As you can run `docker run -dit --name my-apache-app -p 7575:80 -v "$PWD":/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4` and access to apache service.

Run above command and login to running container : `sudo docker exec -it container_id /bin/sh`

`cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`

Copy the content and past in your `httpd.conf`, change port.

No need to add `CMD[""]` things as `httpd:alpine` base image does it.

Just `COPY httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

This is the script executed by default by the [httpd alpine image](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/1f4f7973d49205836c6f71d397382159291aefb4/2.4/alpine/Dockerfile#L156-L159):

[`2.4/alpine/httpd-foreground`](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/master/2.4/alpine/httpd-foreground)

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Apache gets grumpy about PID files pre-existing
rm -f /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid

exec httpd -DFOREGROUND "$@"
```

Try and add an `echo "test"` before and after the `rm` command to check that:

- the `CMD` script is actually called
- the `rm` command is not the one causing an error (and an exit of the script with status 1)

[`docker-library/httpd` issue 127](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/issues/127) mentions a similar issue, solved with the  [Apache `ErrorLog` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#errorlog) (presumably similar to one used in [issue 133, with a mounted `httpd-vhosts.conf`](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/issues/133#issuecomment-487733566).

---

> I have tried `docker run -dit --name my-apache-app -p 7575:80 -v "$PWD":/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4` and it works.

Then modify your `docker-compose.yml` to include the same mount ([see documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)):

```
frontend_image:
    image: frontend_image
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
    build: 
      context: ./frontend_image
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    network_mode: "host"
    env_file: "./api.env"
    depends_on: 
      - apigateway
```

Comment: I have added `ErrorLog`, but still same. Where should I place this bash script?

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram As seen in https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/1f4f7973d49205836c6f71d397382159291aefb4/2.4/alpine/Dockerfile#L156, your own Dockerfile should include `COPY httpd-foreground /usr/local/bin/`, with  `httpd-foreground` modified as indicated in the answer, for testing.

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram Also, see me edit to include the missing volume in your `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: What do you mean by missing volume?

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram I refer to your own edit: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61853292/2. You added a volume: `-v "$PWD":/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/`. I propose to add the same volume in your `docker-compose.yml` to see if a `docker-compose up` will work (like your `docker run` command was working)

Comment: Modified all the locations as suggested, yet same result.

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram OK. Did you modify `httpd-foreground` and `COPY` it in your `Dockerfile`, in order to get some trace at runtime?

Comment: Yes, I have `httpd-foreground` in my working directory and `COPY httpd-foreground /usr/local/bin/` and 
`CMD ["/bin/sh","-c","httpd-foreground","-DFOREGROUND"]`

Comment: `echo "test"` gives `frontend_image_1  | test` before and after `rm`

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram Since the `docker run` works with `httpd:2.4` image, can you try the same `docker run`, but with the `frontend_image` image?